# bufnr return unexpected number

Tags: buffers, functions

from neovim help:

```
bufnr([{expr} [, {create}]])
        The result is the number of a buffer, as it is displayed by
        the ":ls" command.  For the use of {expr}, see |bufname()|
```

But it is not true.

the result of `:ls`

```
  1  a   "trackforlam.py"               line 73
  6  a   "[jupyter]"                    line 233
  9  h + "[No Name]"                    line 522
 24  h   "[jupyter]"                    line 0
 30 #h   "~/vimpy3/mappings.vim"        line 593
 31 %a   "~/vimpy3/hacks.vim"           line 506
```

`echo bufnr('[juypter]')`

returns 1

Why is that? is it the window number? So how do I get the buffer number ?

Comment: Can you confirm `1` is returned, or does it return `-1`?

Comment: 1 is returned. Someone answered correctly but didn't provide a proper fix. The thing is that it happens because '[juyper]' is like regex and matches either j or u or ... . The question is how to make '[' be char in a file pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `:h file-pattern`:

> [ch]    matches 'c' or 'h'

Using brackets like in `[jupyter]` matches a single character present in the list `jupyter`, not the literal string `'[jupyter]'`. You need to escape your square brackets inside your pattern like:

```
bufnr('\[jupyter\]')
```

Otherwise, `[jupyter]` is being treated as a collection, and the `t` inside that collection is matching `trackforlam.py`, which is why you are getting 1 as a result.

See:

```
:h file-pattern
:h bufnr()
:h bufname()
:h /magic
:h literal-string
```

Comment: I tried it before and I was sure it didn't work. `echo bufnr("\[jupyter\]") ` in my history!  maybe because there were duplicate buffers? works now

Comment: If you use double quotes you have to double escape (i.e. `echo bufnr(“\\[jupyter\\]”)`) as outlined in `:help literal-string`. Because we *want* a literal square bracket in the *pattern*, not the *string*, the backslash has to be escaped.

Comment: Does this work with a new, `[No Name]` buffer for you? Not for me :(

Comment: @Quasímodo In `:h bufnr()` it says to reference `:h bufname()` for the use of the `{expr}` argument. Because calling `bufname()` on a new, `[No Name]` buffer returns the empty string, I wouldn't expect to be able to search for it. That was my take, at least. What you are searching for is a pattern in the name, after all.

Comment: Your suggestion actually finds the wrong buffer. I don't get it . `bufnr("\[jupyter\\]")` worked.